Interesting Number Theory Problem: $9+99+999+\cdots+\underbrace{9999...9}_{\text{$2019$ 9's}}+\underbrace{9999...9}_{\text{$2020$ 9's}}$

How many times does the digit $1$ appear in the answer?
$$9+99+999+\cdots+\underbrace{9999...9}_{\text{$2019$ 9's}}+\underbrace{9999...9}_{\text{$2020$ 9's}}$$ Note, the last number a.k.a $9999...9$ contains $2020$ digits of $9$.

This question has bugged me for a while, and when I came up with a solution, I felt pretty motivated to post this question.
I know that a duplicate has been closed, however I still think that this question is suitable.

Since $999 ... 9$ is always one less than a power of $10$, we can write:
$$9+99+999+\cdots+\underbrace{9999...9}_{\text{$2019$ 9's}}+\underbrace{9999...9}_{\text{$2020$ 9's}}$$ as $(10-1) + (100-1) + (1000-1) + \cdots + (10^k - 1)$ where $k$ would equal $2020$.
That would equal $${\underbrace{1111...1}_{\text{$2020$ 1's}}0}-2020$$
This also equals: $$\underbrace{1111...1}_{\text{$2016$ 1's}}11110 - 2020$$
In the end, you get:$$\underbrace{1111...1}_{\text{$2016$ 1's}}09090$$
So the digit $1$ appears $2016$ times in the answer.

A good follow-up here. Let $f(n)$ be the number of 1's after $n$ terms. Clearly, $f(n)\leq n-1$ (since the sum is smaller than $n$ 1's.) Can you give a lower bound?
